# How to redirect a section of a Wikipedia article to another article

Tags: wikipedia

On Wikipedia, is it possible to redirect a section of one article to another article? I occassionally need to move sections of Wikipedia articles to other articles, and re-target all links to that section, but I currently don't know of any way to do this (besides re-targeting every single link manually). The `{{anchor|section name}}` template can be used to redirect one section to another section within the same article, but I'm not sure if it's possible to redirect one article's section to another article's section using this template. Is there any Wikipedia template (or some other method) that can be used to redirect a section of one article to another article?

Comment: It would also be necessary in case a section of an article was converted to a stand-alone article - every single link to the section would need to be re-targeted to the new article somehow.

Comment: Not sure if this is exactly what you want, but it might get you closer: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Transclusion

Comment: @HyperAnthony That might work. However, using transclusion makes it impossible to edit an article and a transcluded section at the same time, so it's not an ideal solution.

Comment: I was going to ask if it is possible to redirect a Wikipedia section to another section and saw that you wrote the answer in your question: using the anchor template (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Anchor). This is useful when a section has its name changed a lot and there are several links pointing to the old section. For your question, I think the best solution is to keep the section and use the "main" or "see also" template to mention the article like it is done on most articles (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COVID-19_pandemic_lockdowns#France).

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to do that.

The only way this could work is if the source article contained some JavaScript code that would detect this situation and would redirect to the target page. As far as I know, there is no such code on Wikipedia.

Comment: That's not the only way. The target page could contain onload javascript that checks the #xxx part of the location and sends you to the correct new page

Comment: @Sparr I think you're just confused about what I meant by “source” and “target” (you call them “target” and “correct new page”, respectively).

Comment: oh. What do you call the page the link is on, if not the source?

Comment: @AndersonGreen Your question was “Is there any Wikipedia template that can be used to redirect a section of one article to another article?” If using a bot is okay for you, you should have said that.

Comment: @svick You're right, the wording was a bit confusing. I've fixed it now. I wish I could undo the downvote on this answer, but the the vote is locked in now. :(